# 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize generic collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to setting generic collection to serialize in web api?
I have thess classes

```
public partial class User:BaseEntity
{
    [Required,MaxLength(100), MinLength(5)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100), MinLength(64)]
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100),MinLength(5)]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(40), MinLength(4)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), MinLength(4)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUser()
    {
        using (var repoProvider = new RepositoryProvider())
        {
            return repoProvider.Get<UserRepository>().GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

How we can see User have generic collection properties. And when I try to launch the application  I have this error

```
<Error>

<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>

<ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>

<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>

<StackTrace/>

<InnerException>

<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>

<ExceptionMessage>Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Users_0D7A537351492F8D419F58EA70B1240500CF0FFF354951D83FA225EA973C5338' with data contract name

'Employee_0D7A537351492F8D419F58EA70B1240500CF0FFF354951D83FA225EA973C5338:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not

expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute

attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.</ExceptionMessage>

<ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</ExceptionType>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can have two causes

1. You have dynamic proxies enabled in EF, and you're sending to the browser an entity which doesn't have the original type `Users` but the dynamic class with a very long name that you can see in the exception message: `Users_0D7A53..`
2. The entity isn't configured to be (de)serialized with the `DataContractSerializer` (i.e. is not serializable)

The solution for the first is to disable dynamic proxy creation on EF or using the `AsNoTracking` extension method on the query to avoid the generation of the proxy.

Related docs:

- [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking Method (IQueryable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- [DbContextConfiguration.ProxyCreationEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

The second part is not probable to be the root of the problem. To solvethis, basically you can use the serialization attributes: `[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]` and so on.